# iphone uitextfield - empties on focus (simple right?)

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a simple question, I have a UITextField (made from IB), and I would like it not to empty (become "") on click, when it gets focus.
I cant find the setting, what/where is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IB there's "Clear when editing begins" checkbox for this setting.
Or you can set it in code setting `clearsOnBeginEditing` property to the corresponding value.